# How to guard against regex injection in php? What are the general rules for sanitising input for all regular expressions functions of php?

Tags: php, regex, code-injection

Looking for tips on what characters I should be escaping in my regular expressions to prevent exploits.

e.g

> Regular Expression Injection
>
> The PCRE function preg_replace() function in PHP allows for an “e”
>   (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL) modifier which means the replacement string will
>   be evaluated as PHP after subsitution. Untrusted input used in the
>   replacement string could therefore inject PHP code to be executed.

or here: http://hauser-wenz.de/playground/papers/RegExInjection.pdf

In general for sql injections there are lots of guides and tips to follow but cant find much about regex injection

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Code_Injection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289923/in-which-languages-is-it-a-security-hole-to-use-user-supplied-regular-expression/4292439#4292439

Comment: You can't. You have to sanitize the input beforehand. For more exploitable PHP functions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3115559/838733

Comment: What are the general rules for sanitising input for all regular expressions functions of php?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead (which doesn't rely on `eval` of user code). That's what PHP 5.5 recommends you do when using `/e`.

```
$str = 'CAPS';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', function($match) { return strtolower($match[0]); }, $str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_quote` to quote regular expression characters:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

You usually want to add your delimiter as the second argument.

e.g.

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q = preg_quote($q, "/");
$replaced = preg_replace("/" . $q . "/", "42", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input) - sort of like prepared statements in SQL - they protect you from any kind of pattern/input

```php
<?php
$unsafe = $_GET['value'];
$pattern = Pattern::inject("(start|begin)@(end|finish)+", [$unsafe]]);
```

and then just use the pattern

```php
$pattern->match($something);
```

Answer (score -1):

**this is only read the letters, and it ignores special character:**

function sanitize_letter ($var)
         {

```
        $var= preg_replace("/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^<>&!@#$%^&\/':\";*()_+=$|#]/","",$var);

        return $var;
     }
```

this is only read the numbers, and it ignores special character:

function sanitize_number ($var)
         {

```
        $var= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$var);
        return $var;
     }
```

**for example, how you can use the above functions,**

**$pure_id=sanitize_number($_GET['id']);**