# what prerequisites you will make to protect [secure] your website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security

I am new in asp.net
While developing asp.net website, what consideration you will tack to make sure your website is secure ?

Comment: Completely depends on the website. Watch out for SQL injection all the way up to making sure credit card numbers are secure. How long is your piece of string?

Comment: You must define secure, more details, what you try to secure ?

Comment: See [my post on how the OWASP Top 10 applies to ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903746/413180)

Answer (score 0):

"secure" has many meanings, and what you do depends on the context.

For instance, "secure" can mean that you want to encrypt the pages.  That means using SSL.  Or it can mean that your site doesn't have common vulnerabilities, in which case you should check out https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet

or

http://www.troyhunt.com/search/label/OWASP