# How to add <li> element with <i> element to <ul> after click in java script

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have small problem with adding  element (close button) to  after click in java script.

Here is the code:

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task").value;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);

  var i = document.createElement("i");
  ul.appendChild(i);

  li.innerHTML = input + i;
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Josefin+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Dodaj nowe zadanie do listy</h1>
    <div class="to-do-container">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input id="new-task" type="text">
        <button id="add-button" type="button">Dodaj</button>
      </div>
      <ul id="tasks">
        <li>Zadzwonić do...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Odebrać dzieci z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Kupić na obiad...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Umówić się na...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Załatwić na mieście...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Spotkać się z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

It gives me "HTML Element Object". I am now learning Js using simple tasks, but here I think there is small detail.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you enable to use jQuery ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing `[object HTMLElement]` as you're attempting to append an Element object through the use of `innerHTML`, which coerces it to a string. You instead need to set the `input` text value using `innerText`, then `appendChild()` for the `i` element, as you already are in other places.

Also note that you need to add the classes to the `i` which can be done by using `classList.add()`. Try this:

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  i.classList.add('fas', 'fa-times');

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task").value;
  li.innerText = input;
  li.appendChild(i);
  
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Josefin+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Dodaj nowe zadanie do listy</h1>
  <div class="to-do-container">
    <div class="input-data">
      <input id="new-task" type="text">
      <button id="add-button" type="button">Dodaj</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="tasks">
      <li>Zadzwonić do...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Odebrać dzieci z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Kupić na obiad...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Umówić się na...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Załatwić na mieście...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Spotkać się z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have also gone further...and want to delete <li> element when clicked on <i> element. I have code like this and it doesn't work. Please notice that I am still learning JS :-) Thank you in advance for help.


            var remove = document.querySelectorAll(".fas");
            remove.addEventListener("click", function () {
                
               for(var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++){
                   remove[i].classList.remove('remove-list');
               }
            });

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question, as that's about a completely different topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `innerHTML` for this one.<sup>1</sup> There are two major tasks, (1) setting the text of `li` element and (2) setting the icon on `i` element.

They can be done as follows:

```
// Create the elements.
var li = document.createElement("li");
var i = document.createElement("i");

// Set font-awesome icon.
i.className = "fas fa-times";

// Set the text of <li> element.
li.innerText = input.value;

// Append the icon into <li> element.
li.appendChild(i);

// Append the <li> element to <ul> element.
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task");

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  i.className = "fas fa-times";
  li.innerText = input.value;
  li.appendChild(i);
  ul.appendChild(li);

  // Clear the input once done.
  input.value = "";
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Josefin+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Dodaj nowe zadanie do listy</h1>
  <div class="to-do-container">
    <div class="input-data">
      <input id="new-task" type="text" />
      <button id="add-button" type="button">Dodaj</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="tasks">
      <li>Zadzwonić do...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Odebrać dzieci z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Kupić na obiad...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Umówić się na...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Załatwić na mieście...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      <li>Spotkać się z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

1 - `innerHTML` is usually undesired because of its vulnerability to XSS attacks:  [XSS prevention and .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661497/xss-prevention-and-innerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code where you need to append `li` to `ul` and assign input value to `li` first. Create `i`, assign required class and then append it to `li`

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task").value;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML = input;
  
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  i.className = "fas fa-times";
  li.appendChild(i);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Josefin+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Dodaj nowe zadanie do listy</h1>
    <div class="to-do-container">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input id="new-task" type="text">
        <button id="add-button" type="button">Dodaj</button>
      </div>
      <ul id="tasks">
        <li>Zadzwonić do...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Odebrać dzieci z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Kupić na obiad...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Umówić się na...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Załatwić na mieście...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Spotkać się z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the `i` using appendChild:

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task").value;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  i.classList += ' fas fa-times';

  li.innerHTML = input;
  li.appendChild(i);
  
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<html
<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Josefin+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Dodaj nowe zadanie do listy</h1>
    <div class="to-do-container">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input id="new-task" type="text">
        <button id="add-button" type="button">Dodaj</button>
      </div>
      <ul id="tasks">
        <li>Zadzwonić do...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Odebrać dzieci z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Kupić na obiad...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Umówić się na...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Załatwić na mieście...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
        <li>Spotkać się z...<i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are appending html object into `<ul>`. Try Something like this

```
var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
add.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var ul = document.getElementById("tasks");
  var input = document.getElementById("new-task").value;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);

  li.innerHTML = input + '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged your question with JQuery... Or, erm, at least I thought I saw it present earlier.

You could also do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#add-button').click(function () {
        $('#tasks').append("<li>" + $('#new-task').val() + "<i></i></li>");
   });
});
```

Or if you want to use createElement instead of adding raw text:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#add-button').click(function () {
       $('#tasks').append(($(document.createElement("li")).html(
          $('#new-task').val())).append($(document.createElement("i")).html("?")));
   });
});
```