# searching employee names on an @parameter in SQL

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterized Queries with LIKE and IN conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303149/parameterized-queries-with-like-and-in-conditions)

I try in my VB.net application to search persons on characters put in a text box by a parameter in sql DB. Something like-

```
select * from employee where name like '@name%'
```

but it doesn't work!

Can somebody help me?

Comment: "it doesn't work" makes not really a question.

Answer (score 3):

For a starts-with match:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name LIKE @name + '%'
```

For a contains match:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
```

You want to combine the string `'%'` with the value of `@name`: currently you are using the string '@name%' which of course is not what you want to search for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle this in SQL you can also do the following:

```
select * from employee where name like @name +'%'
```

**Edit:** Kieren Johnson beat me to this answer and has explained further

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the `%` at the end of your named parameter.

`select * from employee where name like @name`

`addParameter("@name", "obama%")`   //this isn't actually a real function (because I don't know how you would call in in VB, but I think you see what i mean ;-))

also you should remove the `'` around your named parameter