# Building a dynamic sql query from VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have searched and searched for an answer for this and I cannot find one.  I have a checked list box where the user will select issues they are experiencing with their computer.  In the checked list box you will see things like... Slow, Viruses, Bad Hard Drive... and based on what they select I will tell them an estimated cost for repair.  Currently this is how I build my query:

```
Dim mIssues As String = ""

For i = 0 To lstIssues.CheckedItemsCount - 1
 If mIssues = "" Then
  mIssues = String.Format("IssueName = '{0}'", lstIssues.CheckedItems(i))
 Else
  mIssues = String.Format("{0} OR IssueName = '{1}'", mIssues, lstIssues.CheckedItems(i))               
 End If
Next
```

The above code will look to see how many issues they have selected.  If they only select one issue then it will return a string like this: IssueName = 'Whatever they selected'.  If they have selected more than one issue it will return a string like this: IssueName = 'Whatever they selected' OR IssueName = 'The second selection'.  So basically I will append an OR between all the selections if they select more than one issue.  I do this to dynamically build my where clause in my query.

Here is my query:

```
Dim mySQL As String = "SELECT IssueID, IssueTypeID, IssueName, IssueDescription, " _
  & "CustomerID, IndividualCost, GroupCost, Active, ChargeType " _
  & "FROM (SELECT IssueID, IssueTypeID, IssueName, IssueDescription, " _
  & "CustomerID, IndividualCost, GroupCost, Active, ChargeType " _
  & "FROM(cfg_Issues) " _
  & "WHERE " & mIssues & " " _
  & "GROUP BY IssueID, IssueTypeID, IssueName, IssueDescription, CustomerID, " _
  & "IndividualCost, GroupCost, Active) " _
  & "ORDER BY IndividualCost DESC, GroupCost ASC;"
```

As you can see my where clause comes from the first section of code.  My question is this, is there a better way to do this???  I know there has to be a better way to build a dynamic where clause query and I would like to see how.  Thank you for any guidance you can help me with.

Comment: First read information about paramatized queries like [this](http://www.blakepell.com/Main/BlogEntry.aspx?EntryID=054ce25a-1410-445c-807a-cc10bc20502d). You could use an `IN()` clause rather than making a lot of `a OR b` etc, it's a bit trickier to keep paramatized but not [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303149/parameterized-queries-with-like-and-in-conditions)

Comment: What you are doing right now if vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It would be possible to trick your app into substituting arbitrary text into the query, which would allow me to execute any sql code on your database that I want.

Comment: Is dynamic SQL an option... I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Since you're likely to need the same list again and again why not load the entire list of issues and rates into a dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem here is the open door to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). I hope you have a complete control on what is inserted in your `lstIssues` because the string concatenation is Always a Dangerous thing when you create commands for a database engine.

Your code could be reduced using a StringBuilder class instance that helps when you have many elements to concatenate in strings

```
Dim mIssues As StringBuilder  = new StringBuilder()

For i = 0 To lstIssues.CheckedItemsCount - 1
  mIssues.AppendFormat("IssueName = '{0}' OR ", lstIssues.CheckedItems(i))
Next

' I suppose that you have a check in place to not allow to run this query if you don't have at 
' least one element checked in the list (if not the WHERE condition will fail)'
mIssues.Length -= 4
```

This will remove the  IF  inside the loop and, to remove the extra OR, it is enough reduce the length of the StringBuilder instance when you exit the loop.
In your query text the StringBuilder could return its internal string using

```
mIssues.ToString
```

You could also try to use the IN sql clause with code like this

```
Dim mIssues As StringBuilder  = new StringBuilder()

For i = 0 To lstIssues.CheckedItemsCount - 1
  mIssues.AppendFormat("'{0}', ", lstIssues.CheckedItems(i))
Next

' I suppose that you have a check in place to not allow this query if you don't have at 
' least one element checked in the list (if not the WHERE condition will fail)'  
mIssues.Length -= 2
mIssues.Insert(0, "IssueName IN(")
mIssues.Append(")")
```

Comment: Thank you Steve!  I will try your suggestion tomorrow morning when I get back in the office.  Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have always preferred to have SQL do all the dynamic work for me. The advantages, as many people are showing is all your SQL is done behind the scenes and is more secure and cant be injected.  There are ways that evil people can actually (I would rather not explain the details of the hack itself), inject their own SQL into your form and potentially do lots of damage.

Here is the basic premise behind Dynamic SQL (code may not be exact):
You create a stored procedure that essentially writes the SQL code and then executes it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_getIssues
 as 

/*This is where you will place all your input parameters like this
 @paramname1  datatype,
 @paramname1  datatype,

 @mIssues varchar(max)   example: virus = 1 and slowcomp = 1


*/
BEGIN

 DECLARE @SQL as varchar(max)
 SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tablename where ' + @mIssues 

 EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Note: If you ever have to debug the sproc... comment out the EXEC and ADD A PRINT(@SQL)
and you can see what SQL the sproc will run.

If you have to go dynamic this is always a preferred method to go. Also on a side note sql inside your VB.NET code is not recommended IMHO because then from a scalability and updateability standpoint, if you were to add more services, you have to push out new VB.NET code. Instead, you log into SQL and you can make the changes and you are done!

Comment: Thanks!  In the past I have always loaded up my apps with code and I am now trying to find that balance between the app and the db server.  I am using mySQL as the DB and I am finding minor differences between that and SQL Server.

Comment: I am a strong believer in keep all database calls out of code. I also recommend using Stored Procs to call the database. Wether you choose SQL or MySQL is your call but keep the database code seperate from the application code.