# My mysql query is correct but in vb.net is wrong

Tags: sql, vb.net

For Search textbox

this is my query correct query

```
Select tip_part_no as TIPPartNo, date_rec as DateRecieve, reciever_name as RecieverName,
qty, SUM(qty) as Total from pcba_info.lot_info where tip_part_no like '' group by 
packing_list_no;
```

error in my program vb,net T_T

```
("Select tip_part_no as TIP, SUM(qty) as Total_Quantity from pcba_info.lot_info 
WHERE tip_part_no LIKE '%" & Trim(txtsearch.Text.TrimEnd()) & "%' group by 
tip_part_no '%" , con)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove %,' (Percentage and Single quotes) symbols near Group By (`group by tip_part_no '%"`)

Try like this

```
"Select tip_part_no as TIP, SUM(qty) as Total_Quantity from pcba_info.lot_info 
WHERE tip_part_no LIKE '%" & Trim(txtsearch.Text.TrimEnd()) & "%' group by 
tip_part_no" , con
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a parameterised query for this...

Your query then looks like this:

```
Select tip_part_no as TIPPartNo, date_rec as DateRecieve, 
reciever_name as RecieverName, qty, SUM(qty) as Total from pcba_info.lot_info 
where tip_part_no like @tip_part_no group by packing_list_no;
```

Then you add the parameter `@tip_part_no` with the value `txtsearch.Text.Trim()`

Information about using LIKE operator in parameterized queries: [Parameterized Queries with LIKE and IN conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303149/parameterized-queries-with-like-and-in-conditions)

Example and background information here: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)